# vb.net - problem in loging in

Tags: vb.net, parameters, sqlcommand, executereader

I use the following code in my login form. but it doesn't care about cases. Just like admin or Admin or whether ADmin as username can either login to my system when the real one is admin. these are my code:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM tblStaff WHERE Username = @User AND Password = @Pass"
 myCommand = New SqlCommand(sql, myConnection)
 myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User", txtUser.Text)
 myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pass", txtPassword.Text)
 myCommand.ExecuteReader()
```

..........

Please help.

Comment: What is the question? What is the expected behaviour? What is the actual behaviour?

Comment: there are no case-sensitive in my form validation. it means that user can either enter anything without caring about the case-sensitive and they can login whenever it matches the word. Let's see the above code.

Comment: The point is that your formulation doesn't make it clear what you _WANT_ to happen. `... means that user can either ...can login` : do you _want_ to make it case sensitive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be case **insensitive** then the following should work for you:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM tblStaff WHERE UPPER(Username) = UPPER(@User) AND Password = @Pass
```

**EDIT:**

If you want the username to be case *insensitive* and the password to be case *sensitive* then the following should work for you:

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username = @User AND (Password = @Pass COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS)
```

If you want the username and password to be case *sensitive* then try the following:

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE (Username = @User COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS) AND (Password = @Pass COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS)
```

Comment: no guy, i want to be case-sensitive, that's why my problem was

Comment: well, let say that I have a username 'admin' and password 'myP@ssw0rd' in my database. And when I login to my system using window form i built using different cases of username and password just like 'AdMin'and 'MYP@assw0rd', it produces no error. it still logs me in the system.

Comment: i tested it again, and it works only with Password, is there anyway to test both username and password?

Answer (score 2):

You should generally:

a) Compare usernames in a case-**in**sensitive fashion - you should only have one user with the username `admin`, however it's spelled. Having usernames that only differ by case can lead to confusion for other users, trying to work out who the real admin is.

b) Store *hashes* (preferably *salted* hashes) of passwords in a binary column.

That being said, if you want to force a case-sensitive comparison to occur, you can try using a [`COLLATE` clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184391.aspx):

```
SELECT * FROM tblStaff WHERE Username = @User AND Password = @Pass COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS
```

The above only applies the collate clause to the password comparison (in this case, we're forcing Case Sensitive (CS) and Accent Sensitive (AS)) - you'd need to duplicate it for the username column (not recommended, see (a) above).

Comment: i still get that problem. could u please hand me the complete one?

Comment: @Damien: I have the suspicion the OP really wants case IN-sensitive comparison. I think the language barrier is a bit wide on this one